# Where are the publish settings stored in Visual Studio for Office AddIns

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2019, office-addins

We have to perform bulk renaming operation of our code from time to time, and recently when we were renaming our project from C_A_C_WordAddInRibbon to U_A_C_WordAddInRibbon, the project was compiled successfully and there were no errors but when we launched the Word AddIn in debug mode on the Word splash screen we still saw C_A_C instead of U_A_C, after much searching we figured out in the Project properties|Publish|Options both Description and Office Settings still had the old C_A_C name.
[image]

So my question is where is this file or setting saved so we can perform a consistent renaming operation in the future rather than an inconsistent one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above publish options settings are saved in the .csproj file of your Office AddIns. You can edit the .csproj file by following below steps

In the Visual Studio, Navigate to your AddIns project in `Solution explore`-->Right click-->Select `unload project`

[image]

After your project is unloaded. Right click on your project-->Select `edit project file`

[image]

Then rename the `<ProductName>` element under `<PropertyGroup>`

At last. Click `File` on the top left  corner-->`Save All` (**Important**)-->Right click on your project and `Reload project`

[image]